# Scaling one font face in CSS

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I'm writing a tiny website for a book that's currently being printed, and want to match the slightly eccentric font called Cronos Pro which it uses for its headings.  I'm currently doing this with the following CSS:

```css
header, h1, h2, h3 {
   font-family: cronos-pro, sans-serif;
}
```

Cronos Pro is supplied using our Adobe Creative Cloud subscription, and under the terms of [their licence](https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/user-guide.html/fonts/using/font-licensing.ug.html) this must be loaded as follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/xxxxxxx.css"/>
```

This just produces a set of `@font-face` rules defining the font, and it all works fine.  Nevertheless, I feel I ought to keep the fall-back of `sans-serif` in case the font is temporarily unavailable, or for an old browser that doesn't support it.

However, Cronos Pro is a very compact font.  If I know the browser is using it, I want it rendering bigger, as if I'd added `font-size: 125%` to the CSS.  But if the browser falls back to its default sans serif font, I want it at 100% size.

I thought I could do this as follows, but Firefox tells me it's an invalid property value:

```css
font: cronos-pro 125%, sans-serif;
```

Is there a good way of achieving this, bearing in mind the `@font-face` rule is outside of my control?

Comment: You could add a few other fallback fonts that are more condensed and then size for the ideal... `font-family: cronos-pro, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;` with sans-serif you don't know what font will get picked so you can't come up with a realistic size.

Comment: Yes, the real code already has several more specific fallbacks, but they're all similar in sizes to each other and to the default sans-serif fonts on the systems I've tested.  It's the Cronos-Pro font that's peculiarly small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to add a stylesheet with your `font-size: 125%` tag if and when Chronos Pro loads successfully:

```js
<script>
    {
        let font = "cronos-pro";
        
        let styleSheet = document.createElement('style');
        document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);

        document.fonts.ready.then(function () {
            if( document.fonts.check(`1em ${font}`) ){
                styleSheet.sheet.insertRule('header, h1, h2, h3 { font-size: 125%; }')
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Not sure if this is a "good way" to do it, but it should work in a pinch.  I'm still a bit new at web development.

Comment: Thanks.  It's an ingenious solution that works, though I do share you reservation as to whether it's a good solution.  Let's see if anyone comes up with a more elegant solution before I accept this.